# How to create login form with multiple tables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I want to create login form with multiple table using ASP.NET MVC. How to implement join table in login form? I always get error when I combine it.

This is my login form method code that is need to implement join table to get the usertype id:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(tbluser model, string returnUrl)
{
    attendanceselangorEntities db = new attendanceselangorEntities();

    var dataItem = db.tblusers.Where(x => x.userNm == model.userNm && x.userPw == model.userPw)
                              .FirstOrDefault();

    if (dataItem != null)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(dataItem.userNm, false);
        string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        Session["Id"] = db.tblusers.Where(x => x.userNm == model.userNm)
                                   .SingleOrDefault().userId;
        Session["Username"] = db.tblusers.Where(x => x.userNm == model.userNm)
                                         .SingleOrDefault().userNm;
        Session["Role"] = db.tblusers.Where(x => x.userNm == model.userNm)
                                     .SingleOrDefault().userTyId;

        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                     && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("mainPanel", "Home");
        }
    }
    else
    {
         ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid user/pass");
         return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly you get error

Comment: Your code is very prone to null reference errors- after each call to  `.SingleOrDefault()`, you **must** check for `NULL`, and if so, you **cannot** access the `.userId` property (or any other properties). I would make **one** of those calls - check for null, and if `.SingleOrDefault()` does return a valid user - then access that variable three times and store its properties into `Session`

Comment: Also: for both the `.FirstOrDefault` as well as the `SingleOrDefault`, you can simplify your code: instead of `.Where(condition).FirstOrDefault` just write `.FirstOrDefault(condition)`.....

Comment: One suggestion here is there are multiple call to the database better to take the user result in variable then use same object for session information